# How do I escape tokens in CKEditor?

Tags: 8, tokens

For documentation purposes, I'd like to write an article with token in it, for example `[toc]`.

How can I can avoid it is processed as token, and replaced?

Answer (score 1):

I achieve it by adding brackets in ASCII code.